# generating sequences using list of "from" values

Tags: r

My goal is to generate a list of index sequences using this list of starting indices as follows:

```
values <- matrix (1:25, nrow=5)
indexMatrix <- matrix (seq_along (values) , nrow=nrow(values))
fWidth <- 2
startIndices<- list (
  vert=indexMatrix [1:(nrow (values)-fWidth) , 1:ncol (values)],
  horiz=indexMatrix [1:nrow (values) , 1:(ncol (values)-fWidth)] ,
  upDiag=indexMatrix [fWidth:(nrow (values) - fWidth) , 1:(ncol (values) - fWidth) ] ,
  dnDiag=indexMatrix [1: (nrow (values) - fWidth) , 1: (ncol (values) - fWidth) ]
)
```

I am trying to generate sequences using these subsets as starting points using this code, which will, I hope, step through the main list `startIndices` through each sublist, which are just subsets of the original matrix, generating sequences of *x, x+fun, x+2*fun, x+3*fun...* (the `lapply`) part, using a different value from the list `funs` for each sub-list (this is the `for` part), and merge them all into one large list of (in this example, 3-element) lists. It appears that my issue is not passing a proper `from` argument to `seq`, however I intended for this to be vectorized over each sublist, so as to generate a sequence from each value.

```
funs<-c(1 , nrow (values) , nrow (values) - 1 , nrow (values) + 1
    )
    #browser()
    seqs<- for (i in seq_along (startIndices)){
        unlist (
            lapply (startIndices [i] , 
            seq , by=funs[i] , to=fWidth*funs[i]) , #from=n from     indexMatrices[i]
        FALSE , FALSE
        )
    }
```

This code results in the error message, `Error in seq.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 'from' must be of length 1`. I seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding of how the `lapply` function works. I had thought that it would use my the initial dataset as the list of arguments for the provided function, but it doesn't appear to be using the just the list items, but the entire list. This is part of a larger function to calculate the product of all *n* adjacent values in a matrix (*n*=`width`).

My desired output can be simulated with the following:

```
startIndices <- sapply (startIndices, as.vector)
attach (startIndices)
startIndices$vert <- matrix (c(vert, vert+1, vert+2), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE )
startIndices$horiz <- matrix (c(horiz, horiz+5, horiz+10), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
startIndices$upDiag <- matrix (c(upDiag, upDiag+4, upDiag+8), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
startIndices$dnDiag <- matrix (c(dnDiag, dnDiag+6, dnDiag+12), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

df <- lapply (startIndices, as.data.frame)
unlist (lapply (df, as.list), FALSE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Please create a reproducible example `indexMatrix` and `fWidth` are undefined here

Comment: Eee! Sorry. I meant to just include the part of the code I was having the problems with so as not to raise more than one questions but neglected to redefine the variables defined in the function. I've added the requisite values as well at the complete code for the function I'm working on. Thanks for being patient with me; I had greatly hoped not to be *that* guy.

Comment: Since you never really say what you want to do, and rely instead upon erroneous code, you are depending on our error intuiting abilities. My intuit-fu is weak right now. I'm guessing you want to use `mapply`, since it appears you might be setting the startIndices object up with 4 equal length sublists. If you really do want to process only one of startIndices sublists at a time then just ignore the guess and edit your question to clarify the goals.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly with a better description of intent.

Comment: Can you provide an excerpt of the output you hope to get?

Comment: I have added a block of code that will generate the entire desired output, a list of three-element vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see what you are trying to do but from a quick look it seems like you are using both `lapply()` and the `seq()` incorrectly. For `seq()` you need to supply `from`, `to`, and either `by` or `length`. More importantly it seems like the way the code is written now you are using an `lapply()` on a single element of a list.  You should try feeding the entire list as the first argument of `lapply()` or if you need to reference an iterator inside (`i` in your example) consider using `sapply()` as follows:

```
 sapply(length(startIndices),function(i) {
        seq(from=?, to=fWidth*funs[i],by=funs[i]) 
 })
```

Comment: The from argument is intended to be each element of the sublist currently being processed by the `for` loop. I think the crux of my question is how to get `seq` to behave in a vectorized way, which it clearly doesn't want to do.